# how to use function approve() and function transferfrom() in a dapp?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, erc-20-approve, transferfrom

**hello**
Me and my team are working on a staking/subscribing dApp on the ethereum blockchain using erc20 stablecoins like usdt and dai. We encounterd an error on the `approve()` and `transferfrom()` functions, and we need help.

How can write a code that allows a user to approve our dapp contract to transfer usdt on his behalf, and also allows the contract admin to transfer the token when the function `transferfrom()` is called? this is actually needed for the subscribe part of our dapp.

Answer (score 0):

When you call approve(), you are allowing a specified address to take a certain amount of tokens from your address.

So in your case, I guess you would have to call it twice. (Once to allow contract address to take tokens, and second time to allow admin to transfer them)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to implement approve button in the UI, when user clicks it, approval should be called like this:

```
IERC20(_tokenAddress).approve(ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_DAPP, amount)
```

Where _tokenAddress is an address which we can get from the input field in the UI (for example, user can choose token to deposit in some dropdown menu) and _amount is a value that we can also get from the UI.
Then, when approval is done, when a user clicks on some *Deposit* button, you should execute your deposit function from your smart-contract, inside which transferFrom should be implemented like this:

```
IERC20(_tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount)
```

Secondly, don't fully get your idea of

> allows the contract admin to transfer the token when the function
> transferfrom() is called

If you need to transfer this tokens from dapp contract to admin contract, you can do just:

```
IERC20(_tokenAddress).transfer(ADDRESS_OF_ADMIN, _amount)
```

Or if you need to allow to admin contract to transfer tokens from dapp contract, you need to call approve inside dapp contract itself:

```
IERC20(_tokenAddress).approve(ADDRESS_OF_ADMIN, _amount)
```

And then if you want, you can call transferFrom inside the admin contract to transfer tokens from dapp contract.